# Dictionary<string, List<string>> and LINQ, C#

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a question. I would like to use LINQ to filter strings in Values (`List<strings>`) in my `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. I want to remove string containing word "time".

How can I do in the simplest way?

EDIT:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
dict.Add
{("1stList", new List("time", "water", "pc")});
dict.Add("2ndList", new List("cat", "dog", "bird)});
```

Dictionary looks this way simplified.

I just want to delete "time" from 1st list.

Comment: `myDictionary.Values.Where(x => !wordList.Contains(x))`

Comment: `var valuesWithoutTime = myDictionary.Values.Where(value => !value.Contains("time"))` maybe? Can you add an example dictionary and expected output if this code doesn't fit your requirement

Comment: `dict.ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.Value.Where(w => !w.Contains("time")).ToList())`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```cs
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
  {"1", new List<string>{"time", "clock"}},
  {"2", new List<string>{"clock"}}
};

myDict
  .Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>(
    kvp.Key, kvp.Value.Where(v => !v.Contains("time")).ToList()))
  .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
// {"1", {"clock"}, "2", {"clock"}}
```

Comment: But is it gonna remove all items from list who contains word "time"?

Comment: I think you should edit that answer. The last line returns a queryable, so you should assign this to something.

With that answer it seems that that just removes it from myDict.

And you could add a .ToDictionary so he has a dictionary with those values.